# HTML Website opengraph image preview not working

Tags: html, image, meta-tags, preview

hope you're all having a wonderful day.

```
<meta content="Home · Saving Urmia Lake" property="og:title" />
<meta content="Dedicated to Saving Urmia Lake" property="og:description" />
<meta content="gallery/images/opengraph.jpg" property="og:image" />
```

I have these meta tags under the  of my html pointing to a legitimate image but still when i send my links on discord or others, it doesnt show the image preview but does infact show the title and description. My opengraph image is an 1800*945 jpg.

Thanks in advance.

I tried changing the image but still no use.